# ggplot (geom_bar) not sorting y-axis according to numeric values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to sort y-axis numerically according to population values. Have tried other stackoverflow answers that suggested reorder/ converting columns to numeric data type (as.numeric), but those solutions does not seem to work for me.

Without using reorder, the plot is sorted alphabetically:
[image]

Using reorder, the plot is sorted as such:
[image]

The code i am using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lemon)
library(dplyr)

pop_data <- read_csv("respopagesextod2011to2020.csv")
temp2 <- pop_data %>% filter(`Time` == '2019')
ggplot(data=temp2,aes(x=reorder(PA, Pop),y=Pop)) +  geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

How should I go about sorting my y-axis? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

I am using data filtered from: https://www.singstat.gov.sg/-/media/files/find_data/population/statistical_tables/singapore-residents-by-planning-areasubzone-age-group-sex-and-type-of-dwelling-june-20112020.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions are all working as intended - the reason you don't see the result as expected is because the `reorder()` function is specifying the ordering of the `pop_data$PA` based on each observation in the set, whereas the bars you are plotting are a result of summary statistics on `pop_data`.

The easiest solution is to probably perform the summarizing first, then plot and reorder the summarized dataset.  This way, the reordering reflects an ordering of the summarized data, which is what you want.

```
temp3 <- pop_data %>% filter(`Time` == '2019') %>%
  group_by(PA) %>%
  summarize(Pop = sum(Pop))

ggplot(data=temp3, aes(x=reorder(PA, Pop),y=Pop)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth explanation regarding this! I’ve defintely learned something new about r today :-) If it’s not too much trouble, may I clarify what do you mean by  “ordering based on each observation in the set”?

Comment: Think of it this way:  if your dataset is an excel table, `reorder()` would be giving you the general order of the column `PA` after you sorted on column `Pop`.  The problem here is that `PA` in your plot is grouped: each of those bars in the plot is a result of individual lines in your dataset being "stacked" on top of one another.  So, you need to order *after the data is stacked/grouped by PA*, and not before.  Make more sense?

Comment: Thank you!! Was definitely able to visualize how it works after your explanation :-) Thanks again for your help!